# is it possible to log an ROC Curve onto a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning, keras, roc

I have generated an ROC curve using sklearn on python and was wondering if there was anyway to log the results onto a CSV file?

I was able to log model training data to CSV using the following CSV logger from keras

```
csv_logger = CSVLogger('training.log')
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, callbacks=[csv_logger])
```

If there was something similar to this for an ROC curve that would be perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want it as a callback or post-fit is fine?

post:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import metrics
...
fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(...)
pd.DataFrame([fpr, tpr, thresholds]).to_csv("ROC.csv")
...
roc = pd.read_csv("ROC.csv")
```